# Why does mkdir dir{1..10} create dir10 before dir2?

Tags: linux, ls

```
[xxx]$ mkdir dir{1..10}
[xxx]$ ls
dir1  dir10  dir2  dir3  dir4  dir5  dir6  dir7  dir8  dir9
```

When I make 10 directories like this, why does dir10 appear right after dir1? Shouldn't it be the last directory?

Also, if I try the following command:

```
[xxx]$ mkdir -v dir{1..10}
mkdir: created directory 'dir1'
mkdir: created directory 'dir2'
mkdir: created directory 'dir3'
mkdir: created directory 'dir4'
mkdir: created directory 'dir5'
mkdir: created directory 'dir6'
mkdir: created directory 'dir7'
mkdir: created directory 'dir8'
mkdir: created directory 'dir9'
mkdir: created directory 'dir10'
[xxx]$ ls
dir1  dir10  dir2  dir3  dir4  dir5  dir6  dir7  dir8  dir9
```

It seems like now directories are created in correct order, but still when I list them, directory 10 appears to be second again.

How can I make directory 10 to appear after directory 9? Is there some way to sort these directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `ls` sorts files alphabetically.
You can list the files with `ls -v` (in linux) if you want them to be sorted in numerical order

> -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Comment: `ls -v` lists ACLs, your answer is not portable...